# Filtering a table with bound values JavaFX

Tags: java, database, javafx, service

I have a tableview whose data is fetched in a background thread. I have set a filter for it but then i'm getting `a bound value cannot be set` exception. What's the best way I can go about this?

```
 tblSuppliers.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());

//This is my filter
 FilteredList<Supplier> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(service.valueProperty(), p -> true);
        txtSearch.textProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredList.setPredicate(supplier -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
                if (supplier.getSupplierName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true;
                } 
                return false; //filter does not match
            });
        }));
        SortedList<Supplier> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);
        sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(tblSuppliers.comparatorProperty());
        tblSuppliers.setItems(sortedList);
```

I don't want to wait for the service to finish before I'm able to search, but instead, I want to be able to search as the data is being populated. As such, my initial method of executing it in `service.onSucceeded()` will not work for me now. How else should I do it?

Comment: use a simple `ObservableList` in which you add the data. Submit this list to the `FilteredList`

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: note that the error method tells you exactly what's wrong: you either bind a property or set it - not both.

Comment: I know that. Maybe I didn't explain well enough. I'm asking how I can populate the table as the data is being fetched (right now, i'm binding it) and be able to search the table at the same time (while the data is coming in). Evidently, setting and binding cannot be done, so i'm asking if there is any other way, or its not possible and I have to wait until the service has succeeded (all data has been fetched) before I can search the table.

Answer (score 1):

The code shown is very incomplete and full of errors.

The main problem with it is that `FilteredList` and `SortedList` are immutable lists. Which means you can't add / delete items from / to them. Therefore, they need to encapsulate a simple `ObservableList` in which to add data (when provided by the service).

```
private TableView<Object> tableView = new TableView<>();

private ObservableList<Object> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private FilteredList<Object> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(observableList);
private SortedList<Object> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);
```

```
service.valueProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    observableList.setAll(newValue);
});

tableView.setItems(sortedList);
```

Comment: Check the answer I provided. Would that not be another way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

From the search event handler:

```
  txtSearch.textProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredList = new FilteredList<>(service.getValue(), p -> true);
            filteredList.setPredicate(supplier -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
                if (supplier.getSupplierName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false; //filter does not match
            });
            SortedList<Supplier> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);
            sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(tblSuppliers.comparatorProperty());
            tblSuppliers.itemsProperty().unbind();
            tblSuppliers.setItems(sortedList);
        }));
```